# Auto size UILabel text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` with multi lines. I'm trying to get the text to auto size, and fit on the line it's in. So instead of:

```
longe
st
```

The text size should become smaller so that it can fit on the same line:

```
longest
```

Note: I only need it for the first line.

I tried the following:

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
label.minimumScaleFactor=3.0;
```

That didn't work, so I tried `label.minimumScaleFactor=3.0 / 9;` (9 is the font size.) That also didn't work.

Comment: For what it's worth, your second attempt at `minimumScaleFactor` is the right way to use it.  You provide a fraction by which the font can shrink, so if you want it to be able to shrink down to half size but no smaller, you do `label.minimumScaleFactor=0.5;`  Doesn't fix your problem, but it's worth knowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a UILabel with multi lines

Well, that's the problem. The automatic size adjustment feature of UILabel works only for 1-line UILabels (i.e. `numberOfLines` must be 1).

You might be happier with two labels, one being a single-line UILabel for the first line which can shrink its size, the other for the remaining lines.

Comment: Is that the only way? It's a bit hard to do that, because I'm using the library: https://github.com/noxt/DIDatepicker, and I don't know how to add another label to there. (I know how to do it normally, but not in that library.)

Comment: It's the only _simple_ way. The alternative is to take charge of the size yourself by supplying the label with `attributedText`, so that you can have two paragraphs of which the first is a different size. But _you_ will have to work out what that size should be.